# Symfony 6 with TailwindCSS 3: Tailwind components css not generated

Tags: webpack, postcss-loader, symfony6, tailwind-3

I've installed TailwindCSS 3 to my Symfony 6 project. It works mostly. Only the TailwindCSS components CSS will not be generated. Here's my config and the results.

**webpack.config.js:**

```
.enablePostCssLoader((options) => {
    options.postcssOptions = {
       config: './postcss.config.js'
    };
  })
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
let tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'),
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('autoprefixer')
  ],
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './assets/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './templates/**/*.{html,twig}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**asset (pre compiled) app.css:**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**TailwindCSS watcher:**

```
npx tailwindcss -i assets/styles/app.css -o public/build/app.css --watch
```

**webpack watcher:**

```
yarn run watch
```

**Template base.html.twig changed to:**

```
<body class="h-full">
   <div class="gap-10"></div>
 </body>
```

**Results in new compiled app.css with:**

```
.gap-10 {
  gap: 2.5rem;
}
```

Other classes from TailwindCSS base will work also.
So my templates are monitored and TailwindCSS is generating CSS definitions for CSS classes, used by my templates.

**But**

**Template base.html.twig changed to:**

```
<body class="h-full">
  <input type="text" class="shadow sm:rounded-md">
</body>
```

will not result to the TailwindCSS general HTML "input" CSS definitions from "components" like inner padding,demonstrated here:

https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/forms/form-layouts

**For example:**

```
[multiple], [type=date], [type=datetime-local], [type=email], [type=month], [type=number], [type=password], [type=search], [type=tel], [type=text], [type=time], [type=url], [type=week], select, textarea {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #6b7280;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    padding-right: 0.75rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
}
```

And my target app.css won't change its size when I remove or add the "@tailwind components;" from my source app.css.

I can't see my error here. Does somebody see the reason for the issue?

I've tried:

**different import syntax in app.css like:**

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

**changing the load order here to:**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'),
    require('autoprefixer')
  ],
}
```

**less complex HTML template markup**

**static component.css file grabbed from tailwindui.com**
This will work but is not the way, TailwindCSS 3 should be implemented.

Comment: Please don't edit questions to be "solved". Instead, add an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Rick Okay, sure. Done!

Answer (score 3):

I've just found the solution!
The form definitions are a separate tailwind plugin.
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms

So I just had to do:

```
npm install -D @tailwindcss/forms
```

And

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    // ...
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    // ...
  ],
}
```